# Permalink-able pages for Javascript web apps

Tags: facebook, web-applications, backbone.js

I'm building an app using Backbone.js and a private API that serves assets and JSON.

Most content in the app is accessed through the root '/' and the Backbone router serves up views based on the hash (ie /#about or /#view).

The problem is that when a page is shared to Facebook, it scrapes the main page and seems to disregard anything past the hash mark.

Are there any good rules of thumb for url paths or content that is not highly dynamic to make the app more presentable to Facebook, Google, etc?

Answer (score 1):

Google has some good info on making AJAX apps crawlable.

https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/

Answer (score 0):

You could create a dummy page on your site with a full URL that is only accessible to the bots that Facebook and Google use. I'm not sure what Google's user agent is, but Facebook's is listed here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/#scraperinfo

So you could have a blank page on /item/itemid1/ that is only accessible to the bots, point your og:url tags to that blank page and have the correct metadata on it for the Facebook scraper. Whenever a regular user tries to access it, redirect them back to the correct hash-based URL.